# Dreamweaver CS5.5 Dynamically Related Files

Tags: php, mysql, dreamweaver, relative-path

I'm trying to use Dreamweaver with an existing code base (not WP, Drupal, or Joomla!) in a PHP/MySQL site. I continue to receive "Dynamically related files could not be found because of an internal server error." I've been googling all day and have read plenty of WP-specific solutions, including the thread on this site. I've tried all the methods listed, no luck.

Setup Info

- MAMP 2.0.1
- Mac OS X 10.6.8
- Dreamweaver CS 5.5
- Site's local address: /Users/myName/Sites/siteName
- Testing server address: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/siteName

Attempted solutions:

- 1) added library to site root (/Users/myName/Sites/siteName/library)
- 2) added library to MAMP root (/Applications/MAMP/library)
- 3) added include path for both locations to applied php.ini listed in phpinfo
- 4) set Dreamweaver to use Site Root paths instead of page-relative paths
- 5) switched back to page relative paths
- 6) Restart MAMP, reset ports in Preferences to 8888/8889, or 80/3306
- 7) checked site info to make sure paths are correctly defined

When I insert the following code, or any require function with a relative path, live view and preview in browser display empty pages.

```
<?php require_once('includes/initialize.php'); ?>
```

I'm incredibly frustrated. I had been using XAMPP and a plain text editor for previous work and never had an issue with relative paths. Any help would be appreciated.

Answering my own question; bad form, I'm aware.

**EDIT:**

Adding to previous list of attempted solutions:

8) tried designating the server ports as 8888/8889 and defining server route as http://localhost:8889/mySite/, like setting up a Drupal/WP/Joomla! testing environment.

9) Uninstalled/Reinstalled MAMP, Dreamweaver, disabled the out-of-the-box Apache server included with OS X, the redefined the site in Dreamweaver.

Fix attempt 8 led to packet error discussed [here](http://code.google.com/p/mythbox/issues/detail?id=72).

Fix attempt 9, plus error reporting that hadn't been working, but did now:
`// Report all PHP errors (see changelog)

error_reporting(E_ALL);`

showed that the testing server was using the local definition to refer to dynamically related files and, even though that should work, it wasn't working.

After reinstall, created new site with "Site > Manage Sites" and defined Local Site Folder in "Site" menu and the Server Folder in the "Server" Menu as **the same directory**. (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mySite)

Refer to the Setup info in the OP to see my system variables; this may be specific to any/all settings. But only identical local definition and server definition solved the problem. I've recreated previous settings to be sure, and different local/server definitions don't work.

Comment: Where is the "includes" folder relative to your site root?

Comment: In the above code, includes is in the same directory as the file calling it: /Users/myName/Sites/mySite. I've also tried calling it with `code` defined('DS') ? null : define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

defined('SITE_ROOT') ? null : define('SITE_ROOT', DS.'Users'.DS.'myName'.DS.'Sites'.DS.'mySite');

defined('LIB_PATH') ? null : define('LIB_PATH', SITE_ROOT.DS.'includes'); `code` and placing it in /Applications/MAMP/ and calling it with either '../../includes/initialize.php', or a virtual Dreamweaver include.

Answer (score 0):

This error can happen with Dreamweaver and PHP sites if the contents of the included file make additional dynamic calls using PHP syntax that Dreamweaver doesn't recognize. Without seeing the contents of initialize.php, I can't be 100% sure this is the case but I am pretty sure that DW is not able to parse the code there and figure out what files to get for display.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Dynamically related files that I see a lot of people run into:

Dreamweaver is scanning whatever is in you **Local Copy**, it should be a the full installation of WordPress.  If you're working locally, download everything on your "Testing server" to your "Local view" in the Files panel.

If you're working with two sets of files, your local copy and what is in MAMP's htdocs or on your "Testing server" should be nearly identical, except for what you're working on of coarse. That's the problem I see people have.

If you're working in kind of "pho-FTP" environment.